# DocuSign - Selenium Python - "Sign" "Initial" element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, docusignapi

As a part of our web based application, Customer has to sign contract in docusign and then the initial contract gets generated.

In the document, In some places customer initial is required and some places customer signature is required(These are not in order). I was able to do the following. But I am getting "Element is not visible" message. I guess the click is moving to "Sign here" when there is "Initial here". For each contract selected this keeps changing. How do I write my code to accommodate this? Please let me know.

```
 try:

  self.driver.find_element_by_id("chkUserEsign").click() 
  time.sleep(5)
  self.driver.find_element_by_id("ds_hldrBdy_dlgStart_startReview_btnInline").click()

except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print('retry in 10s.')
    time.sleep(1)

try:
  self.driver.find_element_by_id("ds_hldrBdy_navnexttext_btnInline").click() 
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print('retry in 9s.')
    time.sleep(1)

try:

  listofinitial = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='image' and @title='Initial Here']")
  for i in listofinitial:
        i.click()
  self.driver.find_element_by_id("ds_hldrBdy_dlgAdoptSig_btnAdoptSignature_btnInline").click()

  listofsign = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='image' and @title='Sign Here']") 
  for j in listofsign:
        j.click()


except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print('retry in 5s.')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click function will always click on an element if it able to locate it in the HTML DOM using the unique locator specified. It does not matter what is the position the element in the UI unless your are using absolute Xpath or CSS Selector. 
In your case I am assuming that either 'Initial Here' or 'Sign Here' element is visible in the UI and you are trying to locate both because of which the test script is failing due to 'Element Not Visible'

There is a function 'isDisplayed' in WebDriver which checks for visibility of the element and returns a boolean, why don't you check the visibility of both you locators before performing the click action.

Comment: Thanks Rishi.I solved it by using the code below. listofinitial=self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='image' and @title='Initial Here']")
      print (listofinitial)
      print (listofinitial[0])
      time.sleep(3)
      listofinitial[0].click()     self.driver.find_element_by_id("ds_hldrBdy_dlgAdoptSig_btnAdoptSignature_btnInline").click()
      time.sleep(3)
      for i in listofinitial[1:]:
            i.click()            
      listofsign = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='image' and @title='Sign Here']") 
      for j in listofsign:
            j.click()